# MacOS Configure the FrameBuffer as a UserClient

Tags: macos, framebuffer, kernel-extension, driverkit

I am looking to update an existing **kext** which simple opens the `IOFrameBuffer` and modifies the configuration via a call to `setAttributeForConnection()`. I believe that a *kext* is no longer needed as I can connect to the Frame Buffer service as a user client via the following call:

```
ret = IOServiceOpen("AMDFrameBuferVIB", 
                    mach_task_self_,
                    kIOFBSharedConnectType, &connection);
```

With the `connection` I assume that I now need to call an `IOConnectCallXXX()` method to to change a single property but I cannot work out how to make a call that is the equivalent of the  **kext** call:

```
    // attempt to configure via a call to setAttribulteForConnection
    framebuffer->setAttributeForConnection(0, SOME_SETTING, 0);
```

So far I have been unable to find any documentation on Frame Buffer connections. Is there a list of functions I can call using the `connection` supplied by the call to `IOServiceOpen()`